# Flask-Restful Endpoint Throwing werkzeug.routing.BuildError

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am using Flask-Restful and SQLAlchemy to develop an API and am coming across a behaviour which I have a workaround for, but I am not sure the sticking with the workaround is a good long term strategy.

Pretty standard API with a List item resource with POST function and a item single resource with GET function. I tested the POST function via curl and also via a web form, and am getting the following error message:

```
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'brand' with values ['_sa_instance_state']. Did you forget to specify values ['brand_symbol']?
```

The odd thing is that adding a print statement (see commented out print statement near the end of the Resource declaration below) makes the error go away.

And I know that even when the Error message is encountered

- the item was successfully committed in the database, and
- performing a GET on the item displays the URI perfectly fine

So based on this, I think the problem is perhaps with the POST `return` statement. Any help would be gratefully received - I don't want to live with a flaky workaround!

Endpoint

```
api.add_resource(BrandListResource, '/brands', endpoint = 'brands')
api.add_resource(BrandResource, '/brands/<string:brand_symbol>', endpoint = 'brand')
```

Resource

```
brand_fields = {
    'id': fields.Integer,
    'brand_symbol': fields.String,
    'brand_name': fields.String,
    'uri': fields.Url('brand', absolute=True)
}

class BrandResource(Resource):
    @marshal_with(brand_fields)
    def get(self, brand_symbol):
        brand = db.session.query(Brand).filter(Brand.brand_symbol == brand_symbol).first()
        if not brand:
            abort(404, message="Brand {} doesn't exist".format(brand_symbol))
        return brand

class BrandListResource(Resource):
    @marshal_with(brand_fields)
    def get(self):
        brands = db.session.query(Brand).all()
        return brands

    @marshal_with(brand_fields)
    def post(self):
        parsed_args = parser.parse_args()
        brand_symbol = parsed_args['brand_symbol']
        brand_name = parsed_args['brand_name']

        brand = db.session.query(Brand).filter(Brand.brand_symbol == brand_symbol).first()
        if brand:
            abort(404, message="Brand {} already exists".format(brand_symbol))

        brand = Brand(brand_symbol=brand_symbol, brand_name=brand_name)
        db.session.add(brand)
        db.session.commit()

        #print brand
        return brand, 201
```

SQLAlchemy Model

```
class Brand(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'brand'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    brand_symbol = db.Column(db.String(5), unique=True)
    brand_name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, brand_symbol, brand_name):
        self.brand_symbol = brand_symbol
        self.brand_name = brand_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<brand_symbol {}>'.format(self.brand_symbol)
```

Full Error Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 268, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 477, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 587, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 682, in wrapper
    return marshal(data, self.fields, self.envelope), code, headers
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 640, in marshal
    return OrderedDict([(envelope, OrderedDict(items))]) if envelope else OrderedDict(items)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.__update(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 571, in update
    for key, value in other:
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 639, in <genexpr>
    for k, v in fields.items())
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/fields.py", line 307, in output
    o = urlparse(url_for(endpoint, _external=self.absolute, **data))
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 332, in url_for
    return appctx.app.handle_url_build_error(error, endpoint, values)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1811, in handle_url_build_error
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 322, in url_for
    force_external=external)
  File "/Users/skavie/testproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1758, in build
    raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'brand' with values ['_sa_instance_state']. Did you forget to specify values ['brand_symbol']?
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: facing the same issue. Any updates?

Comment: I'm afraid nothing as of today @SangamAngre

Answer (score 0):

The `brand` object is expired when committing the SQLAlchemy session. 
The stacktrace gives a hint by pointing out that the url could not be build because there is some information missing in the object you are returning.

In this case the `brand` object needs to refreshed so it will contain all data again. You can do that by printing it, but it seems a bit better to use the refresh() method of the session like this:

```python
...
db.session.commit()
db.session.refresh(brand)
return brand, 201
```

There is a small caveat however, the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.refresh) of the refresh method states the following at the time of writing:

> Note that a highly isolated transaction will return the same values as were previously read in that same transaction, regardless of changes in database state outside of that transaction - usage of refresh() usually only makes sense if non-ORM SQL statement were emitted in the ongoing transaction, or if autocommit mode is turned on.

This means that the information you are getting back on a refresh could be outdated, but I guess that is almost theoretical in this case.